# Importing a python file another directory

Tags: python-3.x, file, import, directory, python-import

I am trying to import test.py from within main.py how would I be able to do that? Both main.py and test.py is allocated within the application folder. The test.py file is within the app folder.

```
Directories
application folder
├── appFolder
│   └──test.py
└── main.py
```

Code within Main.py

````
from .TimeandClose import test```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:
`from appFolder import test`

Comment: that runs the test.py but is there a way to import it without having to run the script